# Cálculo de input com botão de incremento em tempo real

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um cálculo de um `input` com uma variável funcionando. Tenho dois botões para aumentar e diminuir o valor do `input`, mas quando uso os botões o cálculo não é feito em tempo real, só é feito quando eu clico pela segunda vez no mesmo e ainda é feito o cálculo com o valor anterior que havia no `input`, e não atualizado como deveria.

```js
//botões - e + 
$( document ).on( 'click', '.box-right-delivery button', function () {
  var btn = $( this ),
  oldValue = btn.closest( '.box-right-delivery' ).find( 'input' ).val().trim(),
  newVal = 0;
  if ( btn.attr( 'data-dir' ) == 'up' ) {
    newVal = parseInt( oldValue ) + 1;
  } else {
    if ( oldValue > 1 ) {
      newVal = parseInt( oldValue ) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }
  btn.closest( '.box-right-delivery' ).find( 'input' ).val( newVal );
} );

//função calcular valor
function Calcular() {  
  var valor1 = 3.35;
  var campo1 = Number( document.getElementById( "campo1" ).value );
  var result = document.getElementById( "Resultado" );
  if ( result.textContent === undefined ) {
    result.textContent = ( campo1 * valor1 ).toFixed( 2 );
  } else { // IE
    result.innerText = ( campo1 * valor1 ).toFixed( 2 );
  }    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box-right-delivery">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm center merge-bottom-input" name="campo1" id="campo1" onchange="Calcular(this.value)" value="0">
   <div class="box-button-right-delivery" role="group" aria-label="plus-minus">
     <button type="button" class="minus-button merge-top-left-button btn-circle" data-dir="dwn" id="dwn" onClick="Calcular(this.value)">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
     </button>  
     <button type="button" class="plus-button merge-top-right-button btn-circle" data-dir="up" id="up" onClick="Calcular(this.value)">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="Resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Quando clica a primeira vez, digamos, no "+", qual o valor esperado?

Comment: A primeira é 3.35, na segunda *2 e assim por diante.
se eu digitar direto no input está funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está em chamar a função `calcular()` direto na tag, quando você deveria chamar no final do `$( document ).on( 'click',...`. Desta forma que está fazendo, o valor inicial capturado pela função no `onclick` será `0`; e qualquer número * `0` é igual a `0`. O `onclick` nos botões é desnecessário, porque já existe um escutador `.on('click')` nesses botões. Ao clicar nos botões, a função passada no `onclick` é chamada antes que o valor do `input` seja atualizado no `.on('click')`.

Chame a função `calcular()` no final do `on.('click')` que a função irá pegar o valor atualizado do `input`, e retire dos botões o atributo `onclick`:

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', '.box-right-delivery button', function () {
  var btn = $( this ),
  oldValue = btn.closest( '.box-right-delivery' ).find( 'input' ).val().trim(),
  newVal = 0;
  if ( btn.attr( 'data-dir' ) == 'up' ) {
    newVal = parseInt( oldValue ) + 1;
  } else {
    if ( oldValue > 1 ) {
      newVal = parseInt( oldValue ) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }
  btn.closest( '.box-right-delivery' ).find( 'input' ).val( newVal );
  Calcular();
} );

//função calcular valor
function Calcular() {  
  var valor1 = 3.35;
  var campo1 = Number( document.getElementById( "campo1" ).value );
  var result = document.getElementById( "Resultado" );
  if ( result.textContent === undefined ) {
    result.textContent = ( campo1 * valor1 ).toFixed( 2 );
  } else { // IE
    result.innerText = ( campo1 * valor1 ).toFixed( 2 );
  }    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="box-right-delivery">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm center merge-bottom-input" name="campo1" id="campo1" onchange="Calcular(this.value)" value="0">
   <div class="box-button-right-delivery" role="group" aria-label="plus-minus">
     <button type="button" class="minus-button merge-top-left-button btn-circle" data-dir="dwn" id="dwn">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
     </button>  
     <button type="button" class="plus-button merge-top-right-button btn-circle" data-dir="up" id="up">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="Resultado"></div>
```